# Bit shifts with ABAP

Tags: bit-manipulation, abap

I'm trying to port some Java code, which requires arithmetic and logical bit shifts, to ABAP.
As far as I know, ABAP only supports the bitwise NOT, AND, OR and XOR operations.

Does anyone know another way to implement these kind of shifts with ABAP? Is there perhaps a way to get the same result as the shifts, by using just the NOT, AND, OR and XOR operations?

Comment: Does it support multiplication or division?

Comment: Yes, both are supported.

Comment: Check my answer. If you wish to get more detailed answer, it would be helpful if you could provide some specific Java code examples.

Comment: Thanks jsalonen, +1 given. In the meantime I've figured out a way to perform the actual shifts with ABAP. I'll share the code once it's ready.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: the updated code can now be found over here: [github gist](https://gist.github.com/3160409)

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't just implemented this left shift by simply multiplying the value by the `2^number` where `number` is the number of the bits you want to shift? For instance, we could achieve left shift of 2 bits by simply returning `value * 2 * 2`. For me it seems like a very hacky solution to iterate through the bits one by one, when you instead could use higher level operations like multiplication, `AND` and `OR`.

Comment: If I implement it that way, I would have to take care of overflows, which is a problem with ABAP because an overflow will trigger a runtime error.

Comment: Oh I see. Is there a way you could catch and ignore this specific runtime error?

Comment: I could, but what would happen next in that case?

Comment: Nothing. You just need to ignore the overflowing bits, because that is the way shifts work.

Comment: I don't think that's the way it works with Java? For instance, if I execute `Integer.MAX_VALUE << 1`, the result is `-2`. How would I know the result is `-2` if I would implement this with multiplication while ignoring the overflow?

Comment: No it works exactly that way in Java. If you shift `Integer.MAX_VALUE` left by one, it will zero out the lowest bit (number 1) and shift highest bit to replace highest bit with 1. We know that highest bit is the sign bit in Java -> the sign bit is set resulting in negative number as a result. The exact result is `-2` since for negative numbers are encoded in a different fashion. For details on how this works, see for instance http://www.javabeat.net/qna/30-negative-numbers-and-binary-representation-in/. Btw. as I specified above, with `Integer.MAX_VALUE * 2` you also get `-2` as expected.

Comment: Check out the edited answer for even more details. I think I have now provided you with more than plenty of details on this matter.

Comment: You have provided a lot of details, thanks a lot for that. But it's not helping me solve this problem with ABAP. Like I said, ABAP throws overflow exceptions when I try to replicate Java's bit shifts with higher level operations. I fully understand how the bit shifts work, and so far the solution I have posted myself seems to be the only working way to implement it in ABAP.

Comment: You are very likely right. It seems ABAP works in a completely different fashion than Java; the latter language lets programmers tweak lower-level stuff (like bits) more easily. ABAP seems like it's trying to deal with "higher level stuff only". From this point of view the ability to deal with bits is like letting an abstraction to leak.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I am not specifically familiar with ABAP, hence this answer is given on a more general level.

Assuming that what you said is true (ABAP doesn't support shifts, which I somewhat doubt), you can use multiplications and divisions instead.

**Logical shift left (LSHL)**

Can be expressed in terms of multiplication:

```
x LSHL n = x * 2^n
```

For example given `x=9, n=2`:

```
9 LSHL 2 = 9 * 2^2 = 36
```

**Logical shift right (LSHR)**

Can be expressed with (truncating) division:

```
x LSHR n = x / 2^n
```

Given `x=9, n=2`:

```
9 LSHR 2 = 9 / 2^2 = 2.25 -> 2 (truncation)
```

**Arithmetic shift left (here: "ASHL")**

If you wish to perform arithmetic shifts (=preserve sign), we need to further refine the expressions to preserve the sign bit.

Assuming we know that we are dealing with a 32-bit signed integer, where the highest bit is used to represent the sign:

```
x ASHL n = ((x AND (2^31-1)) * 2^n) + (x AND 2^31)
```

**Example: Shifting Integer.MAX_VALUE to left by one in Java**

As an example of how this works, let us consider that we want to shift Java's `Integer.MAX_VALUE` to left by one. Logical shift left can be represented as `*2`. Consider the following program:

```
int maxval = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println("max value : 0" + Integer.toBinaryString(maxval));
System.out.println("sign bit  : " + Integer.toBinaryString(maxval+1));
System.out.println("max val<<1: " + Integer.toBinaryString(maxval<<1));
System.out.println("max val*2 : " + Integer.toBinaryString(maxval*2));
```

The program's output:

```
max value : 01111111111111111111111111111111 (2147483647)
sign bit  : 10000000000000000000000000000000 (-2147483648)
max val<<1: 11111111111111111111111111111110 (-2)
max val*2 : 11111111111111111111111111111110 (-2)
```

The result is negative due that the highest bit in integer is used to represent sign. We get the exact number of `-2`, because of the way negative numbers are represents in Java (for details, see for instance http://www.javabeat.net/qna/30-negative-numbers-and-binary-representation-in/).