# MD5 hash of a file in ABAP

Tags: hash, md5, abap

I want to generate a MD5 hash of a text file in ABAP. I have not found any standard solution for generating it for a very big file. Function module `CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_CHAR` does not meet my requirements because it takes a string as an input parameter. Although it works for smaller files, in case of a for example 4 GB file one cannot construct such a big string.

Does anybody know whether there is a standard piece of coding for doing that (my google efforts did not bring me anything) or maybe someone has an MD5 algorithm in ABAP that calculates the hash of a file?

Comment: You really want to create a hash for a 4 GB text file? In this case you'd probably better call some external tool....

Comment: @vwegert: Yes, I am sure. Calling for example a system command is out of the question as first, I want it to be platform independent, second, the security team will not allow any system command calls once in production, third, the hash is to be compared with the information from the header and it has to be done in ABAP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the implementation of this algorithm is impossible in `ABAP` because of the fact that the language does not allow arithmetic overflows during the calculations. This should also answer the question why it has not been implemented so far in SAP system. Either way looks that there is no other way as to call an external tool which of course is, regrettably, hardly platform independent.

EDIT: Ok! So with a great help of René and the code of [Fast MD5 Implementation in Java](http://www.twmacinta.com/myjava/fast_md5.php) I created the [implementation of MD5 algorithm in ABAP](https://gist.github.com/3145457) . This implementation allows to update the calculated hash with more bytes, which of course might be coming from different sources.

There is no method which takes a file so far but anyways most of the work has been done.

Some simple ABAP Unit tests are included in the code, which also document how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your work :) I've done a couple of tests and so far it seems to be working correctly. It's really slow though; it takes the system I'm testing with about 6 minutes to hash a 1MB file.

Comment: Runtime analysis tells me the bitwise left shift method takes up about 65% of the time, and the bitwise add method about 20%. Looks like I'll have to find a way to optimize those methods.

Comment: I tried with a 2MB file and it took a little bit over 13 minutes. In my case the runtime analysis has shown 75% of the time used by the left shift method.

Comment: Another test done on some other machine and with a different operating system. File size 1,2 MB, processing time 3:30. With a little tweak in the `left_shift_i` at the beginning `CATCH SYSTEM-EXCEPTIONS arithmetic_errors = 4 OTHERS = 8. returning = value * 2 ** positions. ENDCATCH. IF sy-subrc <> 0. *your code* ENDIF.` it ran in 2 minutes and 51 seconds.

Comment: I simplified the `left_shift_i` (the final loop for zeroing is redundant) and included it in a new version available on `github:gist`

Comment: I've updated the [zcl_bitwise gist](https://gist.github.com/3138494/) with a new implementation for the left_shift_i method. It's **4 times faster** now. I will change the other methods as soon as I have time for it (probably monday).

Comment: It is faster indeed. I am back to my own internal system. The run with 2MB text file which took 13 minutes at the beginning right now takes 3 minutes. The new version is in [gist](https://gist.github.com/3145457). Also the `right_shift_i` can be implemented as a simple `DIV` operation as dividing does not generate overflows.

Comment: I've done some more optimizing, and included an faster implementation of the unsigned right shift. I also noticed your right shift code could result in a division by zero, so I changed it a little. [zcl_bitwise gist](https://gist.github.com/3160409)

Comment: After applying your changes the calculation dropped down from 180 seconds to 165 seconds. Then I spotted that it is worth giving a try letting the `+` operator do its work in `add_i` method and only proceed to the bitwise part if there is an overflow. This caused further dropping from 165 to 94 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could read the file in data blocks of a couple megabytes and create a hash list of those using the suggested function. And then create a single top hash using the generated hash list.

Comment: I am afraid this is not possible as the MD5 hash function does not meet such condition `f(x1 + x2 + ... +xn) = f(x1) + f(x2) + ... + f(xn)`.

Comment: Are you sure about that? Other languages seem to have implementations which allow you to process large files this way. For example in [PHP](http://nl.php.net/manual/en/function.hash-init.php).

Comment: Yes, I am quite sure. The function from PHP is `hash_update`. It seems that there is no such function in `ABAP`. `CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_RAW` and `CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_CHAR` do not work this way. They just calculate the hash for given string or a sequence of bytes and you cannot continue by feeding them with more bytes.

Comment: Well let's see if a bounty will get us a nice answer then :)

Comment: I am so desperate that I started to write an implementation of the MD5 algorithm with `update` function. Unfortunatelly I am getting `CX_SY_ARITHMETIC_OVERFLOW` exception. Does anybody know whether there is an option to switch off the checking if there was an arithmetic overflow in `ABAP`?

Comment: Afaik the only way to get around that exception in ABAP is to use bitwise operations, which you'll need to implement yourself as well. I've posted a solution over here: [Bit shifts with ABAP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349886/bit-shifts-with-abap) I've also written add, subtract and multiply methods using that implementation.

Comment: Thanks for that! I have already been using your bit shift operations. I will try with your `add` method as it looks it is the only one I need right now.

Answer (score 1):

The SDN is usually a very good starting point for finding ABAP-related solutions. I was able to find this post: http://scn.sap.com/thread/1483479

The author suggests:

> - Upload the .txt file BUT as BIN.
> - Calculate the hash code using function MD5_CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_RAW

Are you able to get your file in binary format and use `MD5_CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_RAW`?

Edit: This post even has a more detailed answer using `CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_RAW`: http://scn.sap.com/thread/1298723

Quote of Shivanand Kalagi's answer:

```
STR_LEN = XSTRLEN( DATA ).

CALL FUNCTION 'CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_RAW'
  EXPORTING
    ALG            = 'MD5'
    DATA           = DATA
    LENGTH         = STR_LEN
  IMPORTING
    HASH           = L_MD5_HASH.
```

Comment: I am afraid this will not work as this function module does exactly the same as mentioned `CALCULATE_HASH_FOR_CHAR`, all data would have to be loaded into an internal table DATA, which does not make any sense for example for 8 GB file.