# Working with binary data in ABAP

Tags: performance, cryptography, abap

I'm trying to implement some cryptographic functions in ABAP, and I'm confused with low performance of operations on binary strings.

For example, I have a string of X (not XString) and I want to read it byte after byte in a loop. I say:

```
DO n TIMES.
  b = data+offset(1).
...
```

This works, but read speed is around 1.5 MB/s. Another operations including bitwise addition, circular shifts and modular additions are working slow as well.

As the result, I've got around 600 KB/s hashing speed in ABAP compared to ~100 MB/s in C/C++.

I've got a doubt that ABAP is suitable for processing binary data. Maybe there are another idiomatic ways to handle binary data; or there's no way but extracting cryptographic functions into, let's say, C# or Java services?

Comment: I'd say your doubts are not unfounded. This is not what ABAP was designed to do, which is why most of the crypto functions provided by SAP (you checked these to see whether you can re-use them, right? :-)) are provided by kernel functions.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I need country-specific cryptography that isn't implemented by SAP yet. As far as I know, users have no possibility to implement their own kernel functions (at least because they have no sources of required C headers).

Comment: Indeed, there's no way to implement your own kernel functions (as those are provided by the `disp+work` executable, which is not modifiable).

Comment: Some time ago I implemented a md5 checksum algorithm in ABAP and faced the same performance problems. Take a look at this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351617/md5-hash-of-a-file-in-abap). It looks for example that bitwise operations are implemented somehow on strings under the hood and therefore very, very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been suggested, ABAP is not necessarily the best way to implement system-type functionality, not only for performance reasons but because handling certain data types in ABAP can be quite unwieldy at times.

Perhaps you can implement your crypto functions in C and then interface to them from ABAP via RFC, with your C application acting as an RFC server and you calling it from ABAP via an RFC call. You can find out more about installing the NetWeaver RFC SDK [here](http://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/Download+and+Installation+of+NW+RFC+SDK) and about writing an RFC server [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-52887).